# Distributing files with application via ClickOne

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, clickonce

I'm creating some Excel add-in. I distribute those add-ins via ClickOnce. In each add-in there is an `.CHM` help: in the property of this file, I set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always**.

[image]

If I check the deploy folder, I can't file the help file.

What is the correct practice to add files to the ClickOnce deployment?

### Application Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Application Properties -> publish tab , click on `Application Files` and set Publish Status for the file to `Include`.

**UPDATE:**
For VSTO Project: Change the fie properties `Build Action` to `Content`

`Application Files` button not exists in  Application Properties -> publish tab
for VSTO Projects